# How to determine if it is a ssh shell?

Tags: unix, ssh, alias, tcsh

I don't want some alias to work in case I `ssh` into a Linux box.

How do I determine if it is a ssh or an actual terminal launch so that I can put an `indef` around my aliases?

I am using `tcsh`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su] rather than here. When you do, it'd probably be helpful to include the relevant parts of your tcsh startup file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Normally ssh sets some environment variables (SSH_TTY, SSH_CONNECTION) (see man for more).
Of course you can easily set/unset environment variables for your indef to give false results, but still this way may suit your needs.

Comment: I read the man, for me the variables are set even if it is not a ssh session.

Comment: Looks strange, what value is stored in $SSH_CONNECTION variable when you are not running in the ssh session?

Comment: @justrajdeep .. How are you getting to the shell on the host where you aren't making an ssh session?

Comment: @n-canter i am getting 
xxx.xx.229.250 6340 xxx.xx.230.113 22
xxx is some ip address

Comment: @ghoti
i am using a vnc session.

Comment: @justrajdeep, I think we're missing some vital part of your configuration, here. *Something* is setting those variables. The second IP in `$SSH_CONNECTION` should be that of your server, but the first is the client that connected to it. What is using that IP address? Your VNC client? Some other machine on the network? It is possible that you're connecting to VNC ***via ssh***?

Comment: I am connecting to VNC using realvnc. I searched though all my configs, but could not find who might be setting the variable. Without determining that, I dont think I can do much.